# Regex to match symbols before delimiter

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove all symbols which occur before my specific delimiter which is a colon.

Example text:

```
Pigeon.Salmon-3201@:Cashew123!
```

Desired output:

```
PigeonSalmon3201:Cashew123!
```

As you can see all symbols which occured before the ":" have been removed.

I've found out that `.+?(?=:)`
will highlight everything before my ":"

And that this regex is good enough to match all the symbols, but I don't know how to incorporate both regex's together.

```
[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/@](?=.*:)
```

"Match a symbol only if there is a `:` after it". This means that the regex will match all the symbols before the *last* `:` in the string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ExVMDD/1)

IMO, a regex-only solution is not the best solution for this. You can first find the index of the `:`. Then loop from that index to 0, removing any symbols you see.

Comment: Hey, just wondering, how would I perform this regex for all symbols after the last : in the string, thanks

Comment: @StackStackAndStack Again, a hybrid approach would be better here. First find where the last colon is, create a substring starting from that position. Then find all the symbols in the substring with a regex.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply split on ':' delete all the symbols in the first part and join them with ':' without even using a Regex. The answer to the Regex question is interesting but not necessary here.

Comment: Very true. But if 1 line on the first part contains ALL SYMBOLS the join will mess up, i'm pretty sure. Rare occurance but yeah

Comment: What do you mean by that? `!#$:ABC` should become `:ABC`, right? The join won't mess it up. @StackStackAndStack

Comment: You can specify a split limit so that it only splits on the first ':'. If you have no colons, you might have to handle it differently. In the case where there's two parts `!#$` and `ABC` remove the symbols you don't want (e.g. #) from the first and join them with `:` to make `!$:ABC`.